# S3 Select with boto3 - internalerror

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, amazon-s3-select

Has anyone got "S3 Select" (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/ , 
   https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/04/amazon-s3-select-is-now-generally-available/) with boto3 (or even cli or another sdk) working? I am getting cryptic InternalError below:

Running this on EC2 that has an IAM role:

```
[ec2-user@ip-blah bin]$ ./python
Python 2.7.13 (default, Jan 31 2018, 00:17:36)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> s3 = boto3.client('s3')
>>> r = s3.select_object_content(
...         Bucket='mybucketname',
...         Key='mypath/file.txt',
...         ExpressionType='SQL',
...         Expression="select count(*) from s3object s",
...         InputSerialization = {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}},
...         OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
... )
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 314, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 612, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the SelectObjectContent operation (reached max retries: 4): We encountered an internal error. Please try again.
```

Comment: can you try to upgrade the botocore library? `pip install botocore --upgrade`

Comment: Pretty much by definition, [`InternalError`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) is an error you shouldn't be able to trigger, because it means something unhandled occurred in S3 for which S3 is, for whatever reason, unable to give you a better explanation.  If you have a support contract, consider opening a support request.  Otherwise, consider posting to the [official S3 support forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=24) where an insider may be able to investigate.

Comment: Can you please comment on how did this resolve? There are multiple suggestions in the answer you have accepted.

Comment: I really wished Amazon would better maintain their tooling ... I find it ironic a trillion dollar corporation has such poor api infrastructure  ... nothing worse than seeing a aws ec2 error like "An error occurred (InternalError) when calling the RunInstances operation (reached max retries: 4): An internal error has occurred"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guesses:

- check permissions on s3
- adapt 'RecordDelimiter','FieldDelimiter', 'QuoteCharacter' if neccessary on InputSerialization
- check structure on csv file (number of headers matches data columns, escaping spec. chars, whitespaces, /n as new line def.,.)
- try 
  ...
  Expression="SELECT * FROM S3Object s", InputSerialization={'CSV': {}}, OutputSerialization={'CSV': {}}, ...

hope that helps a little!